# How to use azure B2C with Essentials: Web Authenticator?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials, maui

I am trying to consume B2C user flow authentification with Web Authenticator
(from essentials package Xamarin.forms or MAUI). [Web-authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator)

I am unable to add correctly some parameters required for B2C
like 'client_id', 'scope', etc... inside the url, I got always 'bad url' message.

```
var url = new Uri("https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize");
var callbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://auth");
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions
   {
      Url = url,
      CallbackUrl = callbackUrl,
      PrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false,
   });
```

Did someone achieved this kind of stuff?

Comment: Have you seen this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQoqg4P-uJ0

Comment: Very intersting video, I am use to do it with Microsoft.IDentity.Client (MSAL), now..
Works great with .Net MAUI.

Answer (score 0):

Web Authenticator just helps on the Web Browser-based authentication flows. Use MSAL, which is more of a complete package to support what you are looking for.

This is a sample app for Xamarin Forms
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-xamarin-forms/

Another much more detailed blog, (Similar other articles also, you can find by searching for Xamarin Forms MSAL in Google)
https://thewissen.io/implementing-msal-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/